# Is there an easier way to capture polyline elevation data?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, 3d-analyst

I am in the middle of migrating a watercourse network dataset from AutoCAD map 3D to ArcGIS 10. I have been able insert the various streams/rivers/nodes into arcgis and project the associated elevation data. I fully expect that in the future others in my department will update and add to this dataset. The problem is that, as I work in a planning department, those who will be updating my dataset do not know a great deal about GIS. Therefore I would like to keep the data capture process as simple as possible.

I have used various methods to project my 3d data including the interpolate to shape tool and ArcScene. However, I fear this process may be too involved for some and I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to digitize, for example, a 3d polyline?